# Generic Singleton using Enum & Bill Pugh approach

Tags: java, generics, singleton

Following is my Generic Singleton which gives me Singleton Object for any given class. Basically its a mixture of Bill Pugh & enum pattern of Singleton. Can still this be improved ? please suggest.

```
public enum GSingleton {

    INSTANCE;
    private GSingleton() {
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static Map<String, Object> instances = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        private static <T> T Instance(Class<T> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            T newInstance = null;
            if (instances.containsKey(c.getName())) {
                newInstance = (T) instances.get(c.getName());
            } else {
                newInstance = c.newInstance();
                instances.put(c.getName(), newInstance);
            }
            return newInstance;
        }

    }

    public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       synchronized (c) {
        return SingletonHelper.Instance(c);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place for this

Comment: Your `SingletonHelper` is not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks Glains for your time, as i am using "enum" here which is thread safe by default do i still need to consider regarding thread safety ? please provide your feedback.